# Do C# try-finally CERs break in iterators?

Tags: c#, .net, finalization, cer

Apparently, Constrained Execution Region guarantees do not apply to iterators (probably because of how they are implemented and all), but is this a bug or by design? [See the example below.]

i.e. What are the rules on CERs being used with iterators?

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;

class Program
{
    static bool cerWorked;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            cerWorked = true;
            foreach (var v in Iterate()) { }
        }
        catch { System.Console.WriteLine(cerWorked); }
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }

    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    unsafe static void StackOverflow()
    {
        Big big;
        big.Bytes[int.MaxValue - 1] = 1;
    }

    static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int> Iterate()
    {
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
        try { cerWorked = false; yield return 5; }
        finally { StackOverflow(); }
    }

    unsafe struct Big { public fixed byte Bytes[int.MaxValue]; }
}
```

(Code mostly stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101147/code-demonstrating-the-importance-of-a-constrained-execution-region/1349519#1349519).)

Comment: For what its worth you seem to be the first person to notice this...at least as far as I could tell from googling for other references of it.

Comment: I did find this https://vmccontroller.svn.codeplex.com/svn/VmcController/VmcServices/DetectOpenFiles.cs snippet of code in which the unsuspecting author is not going to get the CER that he thinks he's getting.

Comment: @Brian: Lol, nice. I think it's something most people don't use very often, and those who do probably already know intuitively, without actually ever having thought about it. Just my guess, though.

Comment: I don't know. Your discovery is pretty esoteric. The people who worked on CERs or iterators may not have thought of this edge case afterall. Otherwise you might expect a compiler error or warning like you get when you try to put a `yield return` in a `try-catch`. Just saying...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, I do not know if this a bug or just a *really* weird edge case in which CERs were not designed to handle.

So here is the pertinent code.

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Iterate()
{
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
    try { cerWorked = false; yield return 5; }
    finally { StackOverflow(); }
}
```

When this gets compiled and we attempt to decompile it into C# with Reflector we get this.

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Iterate()
{
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
    cerWorked = false;
    yield return 5;
}
```

Now wait just a second! Reflector has this all screwed up. This is what the IL actually looks like.

```
.method private hidebysig static class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32> Iterate() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] class Sandbox.Program/<Iterate>d__1 d__,
        [1] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32> enumerable)
    L_0000: ldc.i4.s -2
    L_0002: newobj instance void Sandbox.Program/<Iterate>d__1::.ctor(int32)
    L_0007: stloc.0 
    L_0008: ldloc.0 
    L_0009: stloc.1 
    L_000a: br.s L_000c
    L_000c: ldloc.1 
    L_000d: ret 
}
```

Notice that there is, in fact, no call to `PrepareConstrainedRegions` despite what Reflector says. So where is it lurking? Well, it is right there in the auto generated `IEnumerator`'s `MoveNext` method. This time Reflector gets it right.

```
private bool MoveNext()
{
    try
    {
        switch (this.<>1__state)
        {
            case 0:
                this.<>1__state = -1;
                RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
                this.<>1__state = 1;
                Program.cerWorked = false;
                this.<>2__current = 5;
                this.<>1__state = 2;
                return true;

            case 2:
                this.<>1__state = 1;
                this.<>m__Finally2();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
    fault
    {
        this.System.IDisposable.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And where did that call to `StackOverflow` mysteriously move to? Right inside the `m_Finally2()` method.

```
private void <>m__Finally2()
{
    this.<>1__state = -1;
    Program.StackOverflow();
}
```

---

So lets examine this a little more closely. We now have our `PrepareConstainedRegions` call inside a `try` block instead of outside where it should be. And our `StackOverflow` call has moved from a `finally` block to a `try` block.

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973.aspx) `PrepareConstrainedRegions` must immediatly precede the `try` block. So the assumption is that it is ineffective if placed anywhere else.

But, even if the C# compiler got that part right things would be still be screwed up because `try` blocks are not constrained. Only `catch`, `finally`, and `fault` blocks are. And guess what? That `StackOverflow` call got moved from a `finally` block to a `try` block!

Comment: +1, nice answer, but what is `fault` block? **Edit:** never mind it is something related to [yield](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/behind-the-scenes-of-the-c-yield-keyword/)

Comment: @Jalal: No, it's *not* related to yield. It's pretty much just `catch { ... throw; }`, without the extra `throw` statement. (Since they're pretty much the same thing, it's not a feature of C#.)

Comment: @Jalal A fault block is like a finally block, but only run when control leaves due to exception. [Here is a little bit more on that.](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/2011/02/09/99250.aspx) The compiler _uses it_ in its implementation of an enumerable state machine, but it's not specific to the yield keyword.